# javascript disable multiselect box based on selections in another multiselect box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have two multi select boxes one for country list and one for state list

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="country[]" id="country" >
      <option value="0">Select a Country</option>


  <?php 
    foreach($country_list as $key=>$value){
    echo "<option value=\"$key\"";
      if($html['Country Name']==$key|| $row['Country Name']==$key){
       echo ' selected="selected"';
      }
    echo ">$value</option>\n";                                     
    }?>
</select>


<select multiple="multiple" name="state[]" id="state">
      <option value="">Select a State</option>
      <?php 
        foreach($state_list as $key=>$value){
        echo "<option value=\"$key\"";
          if($html['state']==$key|| $row['state']==$key){
            echo ' selected="selected"';
          }
        echo ">$value</option>\n";                                     

        }?>
    </select>
```

I have this javascript which enables the state box when the country selected is USA.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var selectCountry = document.getElementById('country');
    selectCountry.onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('state').disabled = (selectCountry.value != 'USA')? true : false;
    };
};
```

But, I want the state box to be disabled when other countries are selected along with USA in the first one.
Any suggestions please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eBTgb/

```
$("#country").on("click change", function(){
  var option_usa = $("option[value=6]", this);

  if (option_usa.is(":selected") && option_usa.siblings(":selected").length == 0) {
    $("#state").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  else {
    $("#state").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

I hope understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using JQuery.

```
 $("#state").hide();
 $("#country").change( function () {  
    var countryName = $("#country").find("option:selected").html();
    if(countryName == 'USA'){
      $("#state").show(); 
    } else {
      $("#state").hide();
    }
  });
```

Heres the link to the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UV9dB/1/)